# How do I pass the object clicked on in a bokeh network graph

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

I have implemented a bokeh network graph with a datasource as follows:

```
# Create a Bokeh graph from the NetworkX input using nx.spring_layout
graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, center=(0,0), scale=1.8)
plot.renderers.append(graph)

# Add some new columns to the node renderer data source
#graph.node_renderer.data_source.data['index'] = list(range(len(G)))
degrees = scale_degree_size([v[1] for v in G.degree()], 5, 20)
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data['degree'] = degrees
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data["color"] = [colors[G.nodes[x].get("isA")] if G.nodes[x].get("isA") else colors["default"]for x in nx.nodes(G)]
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data["type"] = [G.nodes[x].get("isA").split('/')[-1] if G.nodes[x].get("isA") else "Untyped" for x in nx.nodes(G)]
graph.node_renderer.data_source.data["aka"] = [G.nodes[x].get("aka").split('/')[-1] if G.nodes[x].get("aka") else "???" for x in nx.nodes(G)]

graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color="red") #Spectral4[0])
graph.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[2])
graph.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[1])


graph.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=3) # , end=OpenHead(line_color="firebrick", line_width=4)
graph.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[2], line_width=5)
graph.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[1], line_width=5)

graph.selection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()

graph.node_renderer.glyph.update(size='degree')  #, fill_color="colors")
graph.node_renderer.glyph.update(fill_color='color')
```

This works without any problem.  I now need to add the functionality of bringing up an info box when clicking on a node in  the ui.  So I have tried to add this function to `Tap`.

```
# setup button click
def callback(???):
    return CustomJS(args=dict(degrees=graph.node_renderer.data_source.data), code='alert(`${???}`)') 

plot.js_on_event('tap', callback(???))

show(plot)
```

My question is, how do I pass the information of what node was clicked into the CustomJs?  I have look at `cb_obj`, but it only has the mouse position and I need info on the node clicked.

Comment: The index of what glyphs were clicked on is a *selection* and is accessible through a selection callback: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-selections

Comment: use tap with Tap event. and you can get data from source.data.indices

Answer (score 0):

add Tap

```
plot.on_event(Tap, function)
```

and update your source with indices

```
def function():
    print(source.selected.indices)
```

i dont have your data so cant help more.